# ¿Cómo armo esta consulta SQL en Linq con Lambda Expression?

Tags: sql, linq, lambda

Tengo la siguiente consulta en SQL:

```
select * from tabla1 t1 INNER JOIN tabla2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
```

¿Cómo lo paso a Linq con lambda expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo una manera de hacerlo .

```
 var collection = from t1 in tabla1
                   where t1.id == TuCondicion //Esta linea puedes eleminar.
                   join t2 in tabla2 on t1.id equals t2.id
                   select new { Aqui las propiedades de tu tabla};
```

Comment: me dice: No se encontre ninguna implementacion del patron de consulta para el tipo de origen 'tabla1'.

Comment: tenes que adaptar esa idea a tus tablas u objetos

Comment: Dios mio... solo me faltaba el using System.Linq;!!!

Comment: Muchas gracias Ramiro!!

Comment: ok, marcala como correcta si te sirvio.

Comment: Perdona Ramiro. Es la primera vez que uso la pagina. Si me sirvio. Como hago para marcarla como correcta?

Comment: Al Costado a la izq esta para darle puntuacion y marcala como correcta. De paso podes hacer el recorrido para obtener tu primera medalla y ver como se comporta el sitio https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Gracias nuevamente Ramiro!